# Line Break within Tabular - parbox does not work!

Tags: tables, line-breaking

so I'm trying to create the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    \parbox{2cm}{Stringer/Web} & \parbox{2cm}{Area of Stringer [$m^2$]} &
    \parbox{2cm}{Bending Stress $\sigma$ [$MPa$]} &
    \parbox{2cm}{Shear Flow due to Bending $q_B$ [$N/m$]} & 
    \parbox{2cm}{Shear Stress $\tau$ [$MPa$]}
\end{tabular}
```

However, the result looks terrible with the line breaks happening all over the place and the resulting text looks atrocious.
Please help?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    \parbox{2cm}{Stringer/Web} & \parbox{2cm}{Area of Stringer [$m^2$]} &
    \parbox{2cm}{Bending Stress $\sigma$ [$MPa$]} &
    \parbox{2cm}{Shear Flow due to Bending $q_B$ [$N/m$]} & 
    \parbox{2cm}{Shear Stress $\tau$ [$MPa$]}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example a compilable MWE.

Comment: Also, please include an example of what you think is atrocious…

Comment: How do I do that? What is MWE? Also how can I attach a picture here, then I'll show you what I mean by atrocious

Comment: Try `\raggedright` inside the parboxes. Though i do'nt know why you are using them in the first place.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: Added MWE, better?
How do I add pictures so I can show how bad it looks?
Also I'm using \parboxes because otherwise \tabular does not linebreak for me and I end up with text outside of the page

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: you have specified `c` columns (which are single line) you should have specified `p{2cm}` columns (which line break to the specified width)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.
If I line break to a specific width - can I set the p somehow to be exactly one fifth of the tablewidth so that it looks even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the units with `siunitx` and having a tabular that matches the textwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXXX}
    \toprule
    Stringer/Web & 
    Area of Stringer in \si{\meter\squared} &
    Bending Stress $\sigma$ in \si{\mega\pascal} &
    Shear Flow due to Bending $q_B$ in \si{\newton\per\meter} & 
    Shear Stress $\tau$ in \si{\mega\pascal} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run this code I get:
File `xparse.sty' not found. \ProvidesExplPackage

Comment: That means you have an incomplete and maybe outdated LaTeX installation.

Comment: I have the newest MikTex, which I updated just before I started working

Comment: @Hrms Basic MikTeX or the complete install?

Comment: Basic. I just added \usepackage{xparse} and now it works! Looks a lot better, thank you. Can you explain the code to me, so I can use it properly? I'm confused about \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}

Comment: @Hrms See the relevant package documentations as well as a [LaTeX beginners guide](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html).